# how to extract exact word using regular expression in tableau?

Tags: regex, tableau-api

```
[{"subscription_id":"2","service_id":"2","service_name":"product1","service_category":"sms","rate_type":"high","rate_amount":101.0}]
```

I want to extract "product1" from this string ,not able to write correct expression for this need help.

Comment: Post your attempts at solving this issue.

Comment: I guess `REGEXP_EXTRACT([col_name], '(?<="service_name":")[^"]+`. But a JSON parser would be much more handy. See [this page](http://community.tableau.com/ideas/1276).

Comment: thanks for your response ,. I have tried it but getting this error in tableau : [Cloudera][HiveODBC] (22) Error from server: Query returned non-zero code: 10014, cause: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: Line 9:9 Wrong arguments '1': No matching method for class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFRegExpExtract with (array>, string, int). Possible choices: _FUNC_(string, string) _FUNC_(string, string, int)

Answer (score 0):

There you go.

Regex101.com demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/tC4vB4/2).

`"service_name":"([\w]+)"` - first check for literal "service name", the colon and opening quote mark, then capture what's inside up to next closing quote mark.

However, since this looks like a proper JSON response, you should use JSON serializer instead of RegEx.

Edit: As per @neuronaut's comment, edited out redundant `\d`, as it is covered already by '\w'. Old RegEx101 demo can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/tC4vB4/1), for relevancy.

Comment: The `\d` in the example here is redundant since `\w` already matches decimal digits. Try removing `\d` from the regex101 demo and you'll see you get the same result.

Comment: @neuronaut Thanks, I have updated my answer to include your notes :)

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out , that to see individual elements in array we can use following :
arrayName.ElementName[0] in hive it will give the all elements. to use this in tableau , one need to pass it into passthrough function like: RAWSQL_STR("%1.service_name[0]",[Service Details]).